# How to render react component based on event accurately?

Tags: reactjs

When event is fired, I got a warning message. What is the best approach to update component.Help please.

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called `setState`, `replaceState`, or `forceUpdate` on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op.

```
import Table from "./Table";

import Tree1 from "./Tree1";


class ComponentView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            viewState: <Table />
        };

    }

    onButtonClick(event) {

        event.preventDefault()

        const btnValue = event.target.value;


        switch (btnValue) {
            case 'Table':
                this.setState({ viewState: <Table /> });
                break;
            case 'Tree1':
                this.setState({ viewState: <Tree1 /> });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">

                <Row>
                    <Col xs="12" sm="12" lg="12">
                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader>
                                <Button onClick={this.onButtonClick} color="primary" size="sm" value="Table" >Table</Button>
                                <Button onClick={this.onButtonClick} color="secondary" size="sm" value="Tree1">Tree1</Button>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <CardBody className="pb-0" style={{ height: '500px' }}>
                                {this.state.viewState}
                            </CardBody>

                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to distill what your problem is - your code runs without warnings.

```js
window.onload = () => {
console.clear();

const Row = p => <div>{p.children}</div>
const Col = p => <div>{p.children}</div>
const Card = p => <div>{p.children}</div>
const CardHeader = p => <div>{p.children}</div>
const CardBody = p => <div>{p.children}</div>
const Button = p => <button {...p} />
const Table = () => <span>Table</span>;
const Tree1 = () => <span>Tree</span>;

class ComponentView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            viewState: <Table />
        };

    }

    onButtonClick(event) {

        event.preventDefault()

        const btnValue = event.target.value;


        switch (btnValue) {
            case 'Table':
                this.setState({ viewState: <Table /> });
                break;
            case 'Tree1':
                this.setState({ viewState: <Tree1 /> });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">

                <Row>
                    <Col xs="12" sm="12" lg="12">
                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader>
                                <Button onClick={this.onButtonClick} color="primary" size="sm" value="Table" >Table</Button>
                                <Button onClick={this.onButtonClick} color="secondary" size="sm" value="Tree1">Tree1</Button>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <CardBody className="pb-0" style={{ height: '500px' }}>
                                {this.state.viewState}
                            </CardBody>

                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

const d = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(d)
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentView />, d)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```